# Setting up a Gallery of Images with NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, image, event-handling

I want to display a set of images (with associated text) on my window. I want to iterate through them using a previous and a next button. So far, I have only been able to associate the image with a `JLabel`. =/

How do I go about doing the rest? Should I use a different container for the complete set? Should I load the images on a data structure like an `ArrayList`, or is it enough to keep them on a folder? How can I add the event handling so that pushing the button displays the next or previous image?

Here is a [screenshot](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/3042/screenshotbyz.jpg) of what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still here ?

I assume that you have found how to load the path of each of your images (if they are inside the same folder). You should store the path of the directory in a global variable, and then the name of each image into a Vector if you want to iterate through them. Just store the name of the files, not the entire images.
You also have to store the index of the current image as a global variable.

If you use a JFrame as your main window, you have to specify that it implements the class ActionListener this way:

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Then you have to attach the event handler to your buttons (JButton). This must be placed inside the constructor of your window (MyClass):

```
nextButton.addActionListener(this);
previousButton.addActionListener(this);
```

Having implemented ActionListener, your class has to define the method actionPerformed. Inside it, you must change the content of the image according to the button that has been pressed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
     Object o = e.getSource();
     if(o == nextButton)
     {
          currentIndex++;
          if(currentIndex == vectorImages.size())
          {
               currentIndex = 0;
          }
          //Change the image in the JLabel
          label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(vectorImages.get(currentIndex)));
     }
     else
     {
          //Iterate backwards
     }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This was solved long ago using a similar approach. Thanks for you answer, I'm accepting it cause the project ended up using almost the same code.